# how to add new columns in mysql php

Tags: php, mysql, alter

whats my problem to add new columns to DB

```
//  Connection
global $tutorial_db;

$tutorial_db = new mysqli();
$tutorial_db->connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
$tutorial_db->set_charset("utf8");

//  Check Connection
if ($tutorial_db->connect_errno) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $tutorial_db->connect_error);
    exit();
}
    $query="alter table groups add order varchar (20)";
    $result = $tutorial_db->query($query);
```

This code doesn't do anything...

Answer (score 3):

`ORDER` is a reserved word, you need to quote it with backticks, or use a different name for the column.

```
$query="alter table groups add `order` varchar (20)";
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it's because your column is called 'order', which is an SQL keyword.  If you really want to call it order, enclose it with backticks -

```
$query="alter table groups add `order` varchar (20)";
```

But I'd recommend you call it something else if you can.

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE `table_name` add COLUMN `column_name` VARCHAR(20);
```

Please note the backticks.  They are important to escape the column name, especially if you wish to call your column order as that is already a reserve word in mysql and has it's own meaning.